# SELECT with OPENROWSET from a stored procedure with parameter

Tags: stored-procedures, select, openrowset

I am trying to do  a select with openrowset from a stored procedure with a parameter but it is not working.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
    'SQLNCLI', 
    'Server=SERVERNAME;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
    'EXEC PROCEDURENAME @Set = 'Data')
```

If I run **EXEC PROCEDURENAME @Set ='Data'** it works OK.

Without parameters I have similar code that also runs well.

Regards
Elio Fernandes

Comment: Based on your feedback to my answer I think you will have to supply more information in your question. [Edit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/195443/edit) your question and add as much details as possible. How is Excel related? Which version of SQL are you using? What are the full detailed error messages? The more details you add to your question, the more likely the community will be able to assist you in reaching a solution.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try...

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    OPENROWSET(
    'SQLNCLI', 
    'Server=SERVERNAME;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
    'EXEC PROCEDURENAME @Set = ''Data''')
```

...this should preserve the single quotes correctly.

As in the following example:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    OPENROWSET(
    'SQLNCLI', 
    'Server=.;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
    'EXEC sp_helpsrvrole @srvrolename = ''sysadmin''')
```

Comment: It does not work. It returns an error "The metadata could not be determined because the statement 'SELECT ,,,, is not compatible with the statement  ....". I know that the sp works well because I can refresh it with excel but I would like to make it work with SQL.